# Read Data from text file on server using $.ajax to call a php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my first time posting on this site. I have looked over several of the previous postings related to this topic, but did not find anything that works for me. I am trying to use javascript and jquery $.ajax to call a php script on the server and return the contents of the file. Thus far I am not getting any data back. I am able to update the .txt file on the server using the $.ajax, but could use some help in finding out what I am doing wrong to retrieve it. I do not see any errors being generated from the php script and the events.txt file is not blank. vb.net and c# are my native languages so this is a bit foreign to me.

My js is:

```
function readText() {
        var url = "readdata.php";
        var result = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                result = data;
                alert(result);
            },
            async: false
        });
    }
```

and my readdata.php script is:

```
<? 
$file=fopen("events.txt","r");
$read=fread($file,filesize("events.txt"));
fclose($file); 
echo $read;
?>
```

Any advise is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: All looks ok to me. You can test if it is a problem from the server by putting the address of `readdata.php` in the address bar of your browser, and see if it shows a page. You could put a `console.log` call just before the `$.ajax` call to check that the script is getting that far.

Comment: Hmm, when I hit the url for the .php file the contents of the events.txt file are displayed, which is what I would expect. Maybe I am missing something as far as how to get the value back. I am expecting the file contents to be in the result parameter, but it remains as an empty string when I debug in chrome. I also changed the type from 'get' to 'GET' as mentioned by another answer, but that did not seem to make a difference either.

Comment: I tested your code, and it works for me. I called it with `readText();`, changing only the url from your code. Other things I can suggest for you, is to update your version of jQuery, an give more info about what you are doing. Something is going wrong, so there is usually a false assumption somewhere. Is the url in the posted code, really the url you are using? Have you tried putting `console.log()` throughout the function to identify what is running, and what state the variables are in. Does the page pop up an alert at all?

Comment: The url is the same, I have tried fully qualifying it as well. I do not get an alert popup when I call the readText() method. I have a very similar method that does a POST, the alert() in the success function, pops up for that method. I will try adding in the console.log() and see if I can tell where the hiccup is, as well as updating jquery (pretty sure I have the latest version). When you tested this, did you get an alert popup? Context: This is for an update-able event calendar, events are added, written to a text file, when page is loaded it reads data from the file to populate the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the `error: function(){}` to the ajax call, I was able to work through this issue.

It turned out that part of the issue was permissions on the server (not able to read from file in the file permissions on the server).

Also I was trying to run locally and I did not have php installed on my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

The type in $.ajax should be in capitals

```
type: 'GET'

function readText() {
        var url = "readdata.php";
        var result = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function (data) {
                result = data;
                console.info(result);
            },
            async: false
        });
    }
```

Comment: not true, can see in jQuery source that `type` is converted to uppercase so setting option is not case sensitive. https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L472

Comment: I also tried putting the ajax call in a try catch to see if was throwing any errors, I get no exceptions. If I empty the events.txt file on the server (make it blank), I get null error exception from the readdata.php script, which would also be expected.

Comment: @Billy Moon After adding the `error: function(){}` to the ajax call, I was able to work through this issue. Currently I have it working. Just for reference; part of the issue was permissions on the server and me not having php installed on my local machine.